# Using double loop to fill a matrix in R

Tags: loops

I am using double loop to fill in the matrix using following code.

```
mat<-matrix(NA, nrow=2, ncol=2)

for (i in 1:2){
 for (j in 3:4){
   mat[i,j]<-c(i,j)
     }
}
mat
```

The error I am getting is:

```
Error in '[<-'('*tmp*', i, j, value = c(3L, 1L)) : 
  subscript out of bounds
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are two problems here. First your inner `for(...)` loop references columns 3:4, but there are only 2 columns.

Second, you are defining the matrix to have to have single values in the elements, but then you attempt to set each element to a vector.

If you really want a matrix of vectors, you can do it this way.

```
mat<-matrix(list(c(NA,NA)), nrow=2, ncol=2)
for (i in 1:2){
  for (j in 1:2){
    mat[i,j][[1]]<-c(i,j)
  }
}
mat
#      [,1]      [,2]     
# [1,] Integer,2 Integer,2
# [2,] Integer,2 Integer,2
mat[1,1]
# [[1]]
# [1] 1 1
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This explains a lot. I was trying to accomplish as result of expand.grid(1:2,3:4) with inappropriate approach.