# Double loop to fill a correlation matrix

Tags: r, loops, matrix

I have a dataset like this

```
set.seed(1)
a = abs(rnorm(10, mean = 0, sd= 1))
b = abs(rnorm(10, mean = 0, sd= 1))
c = abs(rnorm(10, mean = 0, sd= 1))
d = abs(rnorm(10, mean = 0, sd= 1))
df = as.data.frame(cbind(a, b, c, d))
```

And i want to get a table

```
   c   d
a 0.5 0.1
b 0.8 0.3
```

where cols and rows are the variables and cells - correlation coefficients between variables.

I do as below

```
for(j in df[, 1:2])           {
for(i in df[, 3:4]) {

  k=abs(cor.test(j, i, method = c( "spearman"))$estimate)
  cat(k, '\n')
  y <- rbind(y, k)
}}
y
```

and get

```
rho
k 0.175757576
k 0.006060606
k 0.151515152
k 0.054545455
```

I used this post [Using double loop to fill a matrix in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25687830/using-double-loop-to-fill-a-matrix-in-r)

```
mat<-matrix(list(c(NA,NA)), nrow=2, ncol=2)
for(j in df[, 1:2])           {
  for(i in df[, 3:4]) {

    mat[i,j][[1]]=abs(cor.test(j, i, method = c( "spearman"))$estimate)

  }}
mat
```

and i get

```
     [,1]      [,2]     
[1,] Logical,2 Logical,2
[2,] Logical,2 Logical,2
```

how to fill the table? Or can i fill it without loop?

- In the real dataset many variables and i cann't use tools like `ggpairs`

Comment: In this case `cor(df, method = "spearman")` we get matrix 4X4 but i want just 2X2

Comment: `cor(cbind(a,b), cbind(c,d))` ?

Comment: Or another version of @d.b 's answer   `cor(df)[1:2, 3:4]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would compute correlation matrix for `df` one time and then subset whatever combinations I need from that. This way, you wouldn't have to run `cor` multiple times.

```
m = cor(df, method = "spearman")
m[row.names(m) %in% c("a","b"), colnames(m) %in% c("c","d")]
#           c           d
#a 0.05454545 -0.40606061
#b 0.75757576  0.05454545
```

Answer (score 1):

The function `cor()`can do that:

```
set.seed(1)
a = abs(rnorm(10, mean = 0, sd= 1))
b = abs(rnorm(10, mean = 0, sd= 1))
c = abs(rnorm(10, mean = 0, sd= 1))
d = abs(rnorm(10, mean = 0, sd= 1))
#### df = as.data.frame(cbind(a, b, c, d)) # not used
cor(cbind(a,b), cbind(c,d))
# > cor(cbind(a,b), cbind(c,d))
#           c          d
# a 0.5516642 -0.3918783
# b 0.8200195  0.1474773
```

And you can do `abs()` for your desired result:

```
abs(cor(cbind(a,b), cbind(c,d)))
# > abs(cor(cbind(a,b), cbind(c,d)))
# c         d
# a 0.5516642 0.3918783
# b 0.8200195 0.1474773
```

Spearman:

```
abs(cor(cbind(a,b), cbind(c,d), method = "spearman"))
# > abs(cor(cbind(a,b), cbind(c,d), method = "spearman"))
# c          d
# a 0.05454545 0.40606061
# b 0.75757576 0.05454545
```

If you want to use your dataframe, you can do:

```
df = as.data.frame(cbind(a, b, c, d))
rm(a,b,c,d) ### to be sure that a, ..., d are from the dataframe.
with(df, abs(cor(cbind(a,b), cbind(c,d), method = "spearman")))
```

or

```
abs(cor(df[,c("a", "b")], df[,c("c","d")], method = "spearman"))
```